# Python for loop appends only the last list as value

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, append

I am looping through a directory and want to get all files in a folder stored as list in a dictionary, where each key is a folder and the list of files the value.

The first print in the loop shows exactly the output I am expecting.

However the second print shows empty values.

The third print after initialization of the class shows the list of the last subfolder as value for every key.

What am I overlooking or doing wrong?

```
class FileAndFolderHandling() :

    folders_and_files = dict()


    def __init__(self) :
        self.getSubfolderAndImageFileNames()


    def getSubfolderAndImageFileNames(self) :

        subfolder = ""
        files_in_subfolder = []

        for filename in glob.iglob('X:\\Some_Directory\\**\\*.tif', recursive=True) :

            if not subfolder == os.path.dirname(filename) and not subfolder == "" :
                print(subfolder + "  /  /  " + str(files_in_subfolder))
                self.folders_and_files[subfolder] = files_in_subfolder   
                files_in_subfolder.clear()
                print(self.folders_and_files)

            subfolder = os.path.dirname(filename) # new subfolder
            files_in_subfolder.append(os.path.basename(filename))



folder_content = FileAndFolderHandling()

print(folder_content.folders_and_files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are after `defaultdict`.

I adapted your code like this:

```
import glob, os
from collections import defaultdict

class FileAndFolderHandling() :
    folders_and_files = defaultdict(list)

    def __init__(self) :
        self.getSubfolderAndImageFileNames()

    def getSubfolderAndImageFileNames(self) :
        for filename in glob.iglob(r'C:\Temp\T\**\*.txt', recursive=True) :
            # print(filename)
            subfolder = os.path.dirname(filename)
            self.folders_and_files[subfolder].append(os.path.basename(filename))


folder_content = FileAndFolderHandling()

print(dict(folder_content.folders_and_files))

Output:
{'C:\\Temp\\T': ['X.txt'], 'C:\\Temp\\T\\X': ['X1.txt', 'X2.txt'], 'C:\\Temp\\T\\X2': ['X1.txt']}
```

The `defaultdict(list)` makes a new list for every new key added. This is what you seems to want to happen in your code.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to make the clear() and declaration in each loop unnecessary

Comment: If this works for you, please consider upvoting and accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem you have is that you are actually using always *the same* list.

Defining `files_in_subfolder = []` creates a list and assigns a pointer to that list in the variable you just defined. So what happens then is that when you assign `self.folders_and_files[subfolder] = files_in_subfolder` you are only storing the pointer to your list (which is the same in every iteration) in the dictionary and not the actual list.

Later, when you do `files_in_subfolder.clear()` you are clearing the list to which that pointer was pointing to, and therefore to all the entries of the dictionary (as it was always the same list).

To solve this, I would recommend you to create a *new* list for each different entry in your dictionary, instead of clearing it for each iteration. This is, move the definition of `files_in_subfolder` from outside the loop to inside of it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I changed the declaration of files_in_subfolder into the loop and the if - that works. I knew it got something to do with assignement by reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the array, from what I see...

```
files_in_subfolder.clear()
```

Remove that and make sure your value gets added to the folders_and_files variable before any clear operation.

Comment: I was only cleared if the subfolder changed the rest was done before.